# System.BadImageFormatException calling CLI wrapper fromm c#, targeting same architecture

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli

I am currently making an OpenGL wrapper in C#. What I have now:

- C# Project - the project that uses the library (ofcourse  to test it)
- C# Wrapper - wraps opengl32.dll functions using platform invoke (p/invoke, aka DllImport), The main wrapper functions and definitions.
- C++/CLI - a seperate wrapper to wrap around GLEW calls native functions directly from glew.h inside the ref class

So far no problem with the C# wrapper. But when doing any communication with the C++/CLI Wrapper throws :

`System.BadImageFormatException Could not load file or assembly 'GlewWrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies.  is not a valid Win32 application.`

My OS is Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate SP1

Yes, I have tried setting the C# projects AND the C++/CLI to target x86 (Win32 for the C++)
and I've tried targeting x64, still doesn't work.

I DO have glew32.dll in System32 and SysWOW64
I DO have glew32.dll (64 bit version) in System32/amd64 and SysWOW64/amd64

I will give it a Dependency Walker view and post the results of all the assemblies.

Comment: The standard mistake is not setting the C# project's platform target correctly.  Tinkering with the Solution Platform selection instead, that doesn't work.   Right-click the EXE project, Properties, Build tab, Platform target setting.

Comment: @HansPassant As I said my assemblies are the same target platform. All of them.